# Stop second sprite leaving the canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I'm creating a game which involves one sprite bouncing around and the user controlling another sprite to avoid being hit.

I'm having two problems:

1. I've managed to get the first sprite to bounce within the canvas but the second one is still disappearing at the moment.
2. I can't seem to get the two sprites to detect collision (they are both circular).

Remarkably I can operate Github so it's there if anyone wants to cast a critical eye (please do!) https://github.com/SallyBoulton/Javascript-Game.git

Comment: This question is really broad as it is... Can you include the code you have and what you've already tried? See more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've put the whole thing on GitHub

Comment: Hmm, just looking at it, it's still hard for me to pin the problem anywhere specific. In your draw loop, the `good.X` and `good.Y` properties are coming up as `NaN`, perhaps because you haven't defined them in GoodSprite.js like you have in Evil.js? I think someone else could look at this and debug the problem.

Comment: thanks.  What does NaN mean?

Comment: `NaN` means not-a-number. It is happening to your properties of `good` because they are `undefined` at first, and then you try to add/subtract them. So `good.X` is  `undefined` (`evil.X` is not because you have assigned a value to it) and `undefined + 2` is `NaN`. You can debug this problem further by using `console.log("The good object is:", good)`. This will output the `good` object into your browser console, and you can explore the values of `good.X` e.x. using the browser console.